# WSO2 MessageBroker:Throwing org.wso2.andes.AMQTimeoutException error when creating durable subscriber

Tags: wso2, messagebroker, jms-topic, wso2-esb

I have a code that acts as my subscriber. I have created durable subscriber. So due to this i am getting exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Error registering consumer: org.wso2.andes.AMQTimeoutException: Server did not respond in a timely fashion [error code 408: Request Timeout]
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$4.execute(AMQSession.java:2054)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession$4.execute(AMQSession.java:1997)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:305)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.executeRetrySupport(AMQConnection.java:621)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.failover.FailoverRetrySupport.execute(FailoverRetrySupport.java:102)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createConsumerImpl(AMQSession.java:1995)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createConsumer(AMQSession.java:993)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(AMQSession.java:1142)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(AMQSession.java:1042)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQTopicSessionAdaptor.createDurableSubscriber(AMQTopicSessionAdaptor.java:73)
    at xml.parser.Parser.subscribe(Parser.java:62)
    at xml.parser.Parser.main(Parser.java:34)
```

But instead od durable when i create normal Subscriber, My code run good and there is no error. Why i am getting this error?
And one more question-How can i unsubscribe from the topic?

My code for Subscriber is:

```
package xml.parser;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Parser {

    public static final String QPID_ICF = "org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory";
    private static final String CF_NAME_PREFIX = "connectionfactory.";
    private static final String CF_NAME = "qpidConnectionfactory";
    String userName = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    private static String CARBON_CLIENT_ID = "carbon";
    private static String CARBON_VIRTUAL_HOST_NAME = "carbon";
    private static String CARBON_DEFAULT_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private static String CARBON_BROKER_PORT = "5673";
    String topicName = "myTopic";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException,
            JMSException, XPathExpressionException,
            ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        Parser queueReceiver = new Parser();
        String message = queueReceiver.subscribe();

        System.out.println("Got message from Queue ==> " + message);
    }

    public String subscribe() throws NamingException, JMSException {

        String messageContent = "";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, QPID_ICF);
        properties.put(CF_NAME_PREFIX + CF_NAME,
                getTCPConnectionURL(userName, password));
        properties.put("topic." + topicName, topicName);
        System.out.println("getTCPConnectionURL(userName,password) = "
                + getTCPConnectionURL(userName, password));
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
        // Lookup connection factory
        TopicConnectionFactory connFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) ctx
                .lookup(CF_NAME);
        TopicConnection topicConnection = connFactory.createTopicConnection();
        topicConnection.start();
        TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false,
                QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        // Send message
        // Topic topic = topicSession.createTopic(topicName);
        Topic topic = (Topic) ctx.lookup(topicName);

        javax.jms.TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = topicSession
                .createDurableSubscriber(topic,"topicQueue");
        Message message = topicSubscriber.receive();
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("textMessage.getText() = "
                    + textMessage.getText());
            messageContent = textMessage.getText();
        }
        topicSubscriber.close();
        topicSession.close();
        topicConnection.stop();
        topicConnection.close();


        return messageContent;
    }

    public String getTCPConnectionURL(String username, String password) {
        return new StringBuffer().append("amqp://").append(username)
                .append(":").append(password).append("@")
                .append(CARBON_CLIENT_ID).append("/")
                .append(CARBON_VIRTUAL_HOST_NAME).append("?brokerlist='tcp://")
                .append(CARBON_DEFAULT_HOSTNAME).append(":")
                .append(CARBON_BROKER_PORT).append("'").toString();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in the MB 2.0.1 distribution with the durable subscribers. The reason for this is when the Parser class first runs, receives a message, and the subscriber is stopped, then when you start the Parser for the second time, it fails to starts the subscription back as the previous 'subscriber' entry is still there, and you will see the following  in the terminal.The client will be timed out after few tries which is why you get the error log.

```
[2013-04-22 12:12:52,617]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Closing channel due to: Cannot subscribe to queue carbon:topicQueue as it already has an existing exclusive consumer
[2013-04-22 12:12:52,621]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Channel[1] awaiting closure - processing close-ok
[2013-04-22 12:12:52,621]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.handler.ChannelCloseOkHandler} -  Received channel-close-ok for channel-id 1
```

This issue has been fixed in MB 2.1.0 release which is expected to be out in the coming weeks. If you need please try your sample subscriber with MB 2.1.0 - Alpha version from [here](http://dist.wso2.org/downloads/message-broker/2.1.0/alpha/wso2mb-2.1.0.zip). This should work fine with that pack.

About unsubscribing from a topic add the following line into your Parser code and run back when you need to unsubscribe.

```
topicSubscriber.close();
**topicSession.unsubscribe("topicQueue"); // add the name used to   identify the subscription in the place of "topicQueue"**
topicSession.close();
topicConnection.stop();
topicConnection.close();
```

Comment: what does this mean? add the name used to identify the subscription in the place of "topicQueue"**. I have provided the topic name in place of topicqueue but it doesn't get unsubscribed and i still get the same error:(

Comment: I have given the correct code for your case so you don't have to change the 'topicQueue'. This is what you give in,  javax.jms.TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = topicSession
                .createDurableSubscriber(topic,"topicQueue"); as the subscription name. You should not give "myTopic" as subscription name. it is the topic name which you try to connect.